# what's the best approach to converting a single file macruby script to a full app?

Tags: xcode4, macruby

i'm looking to convert/translate an existing macruby script that runs as a statusbar app. so far, i have methods that do what i want within the class (setting preferences, opening a web page, scraping a page for details, etc.).

the basics are here: [statusbar app](https://github.com/rockpapergoat/macruby/blob/master/statusbar.rb)

my goal is to distribute this app internally, but all clients are virtually guaranteed not to have the macruby framework installed.

macrubyc in version 0.10 appears to be unable to compile a static binary.

so how should i setup my xcode project and interface elements to perform the same functionality the standalone script has now? i'm below novice with objective-c/cocoa, so i'm fumbling along there as well.

i appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

If 0.10 is an issue, use the nightly build and make sure to embed MacRuby. See the wiki entry on embedding MacRuby: https://github.com/macruby/macruby/wiki/Embeds-the-MacRuby-into-your-Application